# NDA Cost Liability

Tags: non-disclosure

I'm not entirely familliar with NDA's and reading through, this section seems unclear to me.

> The Developer is liable for all costs, expenses and expenditures
>   including, and without limitation, the complete legal costs incurred
>   by the Inventor in enforcing this Agreement as a result of any default
>   of this Agreement by the Developer.

This seems awfully broad. Is this normal and am I safe agreeing to this? Would it be reasonable to send back a request for ammendment?

Comment: This basically means that if you breach the NDA and they sue you in court *and you lose* that they can also recover the lawyers fees/court costs for suing you as part of the judgement. The only thing I'd ask for is a reciprocity clause, that if they sue you and they lose, that they pay your fees/costs. Whether or not they can do this may be jurisdiction dependent, some courts won't entertain lawyers fees as part of a judgement. Where is this NDA enforced?

Answer (score -2):

> Is this normal and am I safe agreeing to this? Would it be reasonable to send back a request for ammendment?

That type of clauses is not unusual, but your decision should be made only in accordance to what is acceptable *to you*.

Ron Beyer's [suggestion of reciprocity](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/49083/nda-cost-liability#comment95840_49083) is a valid, reasonable approach. I, by contrast, would reject any clause that involves paying the counterparty's attorney fees because these often are abusive. Court costs are oftentimes a very small fraction of what lawyers bill even for a relatively simple case. The fact that this clause refers to *actual* costs rather than *reasonable* costs will make it harder for you to dispute the lawyer's overpriced services.

Furthermore, you basically are gambling if your case is presided by [literally a felon](http://www.oneclubofjusticides.com/2018/04/felon-carol-kuhnke-seeks-reelection-as.html) whose judicial mentality is all about siding with ["*anybody who's powerful*"](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Ck7HHqFkIaE/Wsoe0CGdR0I/AAAAAAAAARY/OucDrTd_kOAXRwHpcjSKoFsfyWEc0hTjQCLcBGAs/s1600/employers.jpg). The clause as submitted to you only raises the stakes (in regard to attorney fees) with essentially no benefit to you.